# Apply a function to lists in a list

Tags: haskell

I want a function that in each of the lists of a list ([[],[],[]]) makes the sum of the elements and if it is even add to that list a 0 and a 1, otherwise.

I tried with this, but it just does correct for the head of the list, I don't know how to make to the others.

```
 func :: Matrix -> Matrix
 func (Matr size (x:xs))
                |sum(x) `mod` 2 == 0 = (Matr size ((0:x):xs))
                |otherwise = (Matr size ((1:x):xs))
```

With my attempt:

```
 [1,1,0,0]
 [1,0,0]
 [1,1,0]
```

What I want:

```
 [1,1,0,0]
 [1,1,0,0]
 [0,1,1,0]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use explicit recursion when you want to apply the same operation to all elements of a list, let `map` do that for you.

```
func :: Matrix -> Matrix
func (Matr size xs) = Matr size $ map prependParity xs
  where prependParity x
               | even $ sum x  = 0:x
               | otherwise     = 1:x
```

Comment: Good!  I think explicit recursion should be one of those "last resort" situations.  In fact, I wish functional programming texts LED with higher order functions to get people in the right frame of mind and only grudgingly explained recursion at the end. The real gold lies in abstracting away iteration itself, not implementing it via recursion.

Comment: note that `sum x \`mod\` 2 == 0` is equivalent to `(even . sum) x`

Comment: @user1161318: I agree, though it still can't hurt to keep recursion in mind and remember these higher-order functions themselves use it.